# Selenium-Java: Dentro de un forEach no recorre toda la lista cuando llego a un condicional

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

estoy sacando con un foreach una lista de elementos para cuando localice un elemento pase por la condición. Pero directamente solo me saca el 1º de la lista y no continua todo el flujo. Os paso mi metodo:

```
public boolean accountInternational(){
    //localizamos si tenemos más de una en la lista -> ok
   if (accountInternational.size()>1) {
       int contador = 0;
    // sacamos toda la lista con un webelement
           for (WebElement element:numberAccountInternational) {
               String numberAccount = element.getText();
   //siempre llega el primero de la lista y se pasa al else
               if (numberAccount.contains(destinationAccountInternational)) {
                   System.out.println("ELEGIMOS ELEMENTO");
                   clickOnTheButton(numberAccount,getDriver());

               } else {
                   clickOnTheButton(accountInternational.get(1));
               }
               contador ++;
           }
   }
    return true;
```

**numberAccountInternational** es una lista de webelement

**destinationAccountInternational** es un string de una cuenta

Espero que me podáis ayudar, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Ya conseguí realizar esta función. Añadiendo una lista para guardar la lista de un ciclo - for.

```
public boolean accountInternational(){

    List<String> international = new ArrayList<>();
    waitUntilListIsVisible(accountInternational, 30);
   if (accountInternational.size()>1) {
       for (int i =0; i<numberAccountInternational.size();i++){
           String numberInternational = numberAccountInternational.get(i).getText();
           international.add(numberInternational);
       }
       if (international.contains(destinationAccountInternational)) {
           System.out.println("ELEGIMOS ELEMENTO");
           scrollIntoViewWebElement(numberAccountInternational.get(9));
          clickOnTheButton(numberAccountInternational.get(9));
       } else {
           clickOnTheButton(accountInternational.get(1));
       }

   }
    return true;
}
```